# How to disable Device mapper package from kickstart?

Tags: linux, package-management, device-mapper, kickstart

Can anyone tell me how to disable/exclude Device mapper package from kickstart file.

Comment: ... Why? Things like LVM and filesystem encryption require device mapper to be installed.

Comment: i tried to mount one of my linux partitions(/dev/sda4) which is already mounted, but got the following error:
mount: /dev/sdb4 already mounted or /test busy 
according to mtab /dev/sdb4 is already mounted
i want to mount /dev/sda4 in any case and after some googling came to know that disabling device mapper may help.
So is there any way to resolve this mount problem?

Comment: LVM, filesystem encryption, and linux fakeRAID support all use Device Mapper.  if DM has grabbed both /dev/sda4 and /dev/sdb4 ... did you perhaps set those two drives as RAID drives?  (why are you trying to mount an already-mounted drive anyway?)

Comment: How about instead of asking about what you *think* will solve the problem, you ask about the *problem itself*?